# Rhino mock stub error

Tags: c#, mstest, rhino-mocks

I am new to Mock testing and i have created a Unit Test using RhinoMock.
First stub is running proper but second is throwing Null Exception, code is as below.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        SetUp(); //bind List ftsController and ftsEreceiptNumberPrefix
        MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
        var ftsUnitOfWork = mocks.StrictMock<IFtsUnitOfWork>();

        ftsUnitOfWork.Stub(x => x.Repository<FtsController>().Get()).Return(ftsController.AsQueryable());


        ftsUnitOfWork.Stub(x =>
        {
            if (x.Repository<FtsPrefix>() == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Input cannot be null");
            }
            x.Repository<FtsPrefix>().Get();
        }).Return(ftsPrefix.AsQueryable());
        ;
        BoGeneratePrefix generateEreceiptPrefix = new BoGeneratePrefix (logger,ftsUnitOfWork);
        generatePrefix.ProcessJob(null);
    }
```

ProcessJob :

```
public class BoGeneratePrefix : IBoDataPurging
{

    #region private Variables

    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _ftsUnitOfWork;
    private readonly string _defaultTraceCategory;

    #endregion

    #region BoGeneratePrefix Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialized class oject BoGeneratePrefix
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger"></param>
    /// <param name="ftsUoW"></param>
    public BoGeneratePrefix(ILogger logger, IFtsUnitOfWork ftsUoW)
    {
        _defaultTraceCategory = GetType().Name;
        _logger = logger;
        _ftsUnitOfWork = ftsUoW;

    }
public void ProcessJob(Configuration hconfiguration)
    {
        try
        {
            var lstController = _ftsUnitOfWork.Repository<FtsController>().Get().Select(x => x. Id).Distinct().AsNoTracking();

            foreach (var Id in lstController.ToList())
            {
                var prefix = _ftsUnitOfWork.Repository<FtsPrefix>()
                        .Get(x => x. Id == Id
                        && x.Status == Constants.NotPrefix).Count();

                var ignoreForLowerSafePoint =
                    _ftsUnitOfWork.Repository<ConfigurationParameter>()
                        .Get(y => y.ParamType == Constants.IgnoreForLowerSafePoint &&
                                y.ParamName == Id)
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .Select(t => t.ParamValues).SingleOrDefault();


                var currentTime = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString(Constants.HHmmssTime),
                                Constants.HHmmssTime,
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;

                if ( !( hconfiguration.StartTime <= currentTime
                    && hconfiguration.EndTime >= currentTime))
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

repository :

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : class
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Delete the record from the database by accepting the input parameter as id
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">Parameter id is used to delete record from the database</param>
    void Delete(object id);

    /// <summary>
    /// Delete the enity 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entityToDelete"></param>
    void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete);

    /// <summary>
    /// Get Queryable by passing the Expression 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filter">this is used for filter parameter/Expression of query</param>
    /// <param name="orderBy">Passing condition of orderBy for query</param>
    /// <param name="includeProperties">Properties to be included in to the query while generating the query on filter/order by</param>
    /// <returns>Entity type Queryable i.e. creates query depend upon accepted entity type as input parameter</returns>
    #pragma warning disable S2360
    IQueryable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "");
    #pragma warning restore S2360
    /// <summary>
    /// Get Queryable by accepting the input parameter as modifiedSinceTimestamp
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="modifiedSinceTimestamp"> modifiedSinceTimestamp </param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetModifiedSince(long modifiedSinceTimestamp);

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides information of an entity by accepting the input parameters
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">it gives the enity on the id condition </param>
    /// <returns>Returns Entity </returns>
    TEntity GetById(params object[] id);

    /// <summary>
    /// Inserts all changes made in this context as a Focus business transaction and enlists it for data insertion.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">Entity i.e. object of generic type </param>
    void Insert(TEntity entity);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gives information about which entity to update 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entityToUpdate">information about to update an enity</param>
    void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate);

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="query"></param>
    /// <param name="parameters"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    IEnumerable<TEntity> ExecWithStoreProcedure(string query, params object[] parameters);

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entityToUpdate"></param>
    void Detach(TEntity entityToUpdate);
}
```

UnitofWork -

```
public class FtsUnitOfWork : IFtsUnitOfWork
{
    #region local variables

    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private IFtsDbProvider _ftsDbProvider;
    private readonly string _defaultTraceCategory;
    private DbContext _context;
    private Hashtable _repositories;

    #endregion local variables

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor for Fts Unit Of Work
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger"></param>
    /// <param name="ftsDbProvider"></param>
    public FtsUnitOfWork(ILogger logger, IFtsDbProvider ftsDbProvider)
    {
        _defaultTraceCategory = GetType().Name;
        _logger = logger;
        _logger.WriteTrace("FtsUnitOfWork: Initializing", _defaultTraceCategory);
        _ftsDbProvider = ftsDbProvider;
        _context = new FtsDbContext(_logger, "FtsDbStore", _ftsDbProvider.GetFtsDbCompiledModel());
        _logger.WriteTrace("FtsUnitOfWork: Initialized", _defaultTraceCategory);

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Saves all changes made in this context as a Focus business transaction and enlists it for data consolidation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public virtual int Save()
    {
        try
        {
            return _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Optimistic_Concurrency_Check");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="focusDtTransactionId"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public int Save(Guid focusDtTransactionId)
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Generic Repository this function creates the Repository by accepting the parameter as Entity type
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : class
    {
        if (_repositories == null)
        {
            _repositories = new Hashtable();
        }
        var type = typeof(T).Name;

        if (!_repositories.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            var repositoryType = typeof(Repository<>);

            var repositoryInstance =
                Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType
                        .MakeGenericType(typeof(T)), _context);

            _repositories.Add(type, repositoryInstance);
        }

        return (IRepository<T>)_repositories[type];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T1"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="sqlParameters"></param>
    /// <param name="spName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<T1> GetMany<T1>(SqlParameter[] sqlParameters, string spName)
    {
        return _context.Database.SqlQuery<T1>(spName, sqlParameters).ToList();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="isolationLevel"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public DbContextTransaction GetDbContextTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
    {
        return _context.Database.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel);
    }

    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool _disposedValue; // To detect redundant calls

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing"></param>
    public virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _logger.WriteTrace("FtsUnitOfWork: Disposing", _defaultTraceCategory);
                _ftsDbProvider = null;
                _repositories = null;
                this._context.Dispose();
                this._context = null;
                _logger.WriteTrace("FtsUnitOfWork: Disposed", _defaultTraceCategory);
            }
            _disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion


}
```

If i commented out first stub then second stub work properly otherwise throws below error :

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in Fts.Services.Housekeeping.Tests.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Value cannot be null.

Comment: the `IFtsUnitOfWork` interface is being stubbed no need to show the implementation. the `BoGeneratePrefix` class seems to be the system under test. show that class and make sure to include `ProcessJob` method under test.

Comment: you pass a `null` value for `hconfiguration` in the test but access it in the code `!( hconfiguration.StartTime <= currentTime
                    && hconfiguration.EndTime >= currentTime)`. this will result in the error you encountered.

Comment: i am getting error in test method at this line   :                                   `ftsUnitOfWork.Stub(x =>
        {
            if (x.Repository<FtsPrefix>() == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Input cannot be null");
            }
            x.Repository<FtsPrefix>().Get();
        }).Return(ftsPrefix.AsQueryable());`                                               not in the actual metod processjob() method

Comment: Then remove it. Why are you checking that there anyway? just create the stub `ftsUnitOfWork.Stub(x => x.Repository<FtsPrefix>().Get()).Return(ftsPrefix.AsQueryable());`

Comment: I put that line to confirm that x.repository is getting null

Comment: That is not how the stub works. http://www.wrightfully.com/using-rhino-mocks-quick-guide-to-generating-mocks-and-stubs/

Comment: I read that link which u have given. but i am not able to resolve my problem. i have multiple database call with the unitofwork and after using at first time its getting null(x.Repository<FtsPrefix>) and i feel that we cannot use(stub) with same repository(Mock object) for multiple class.